# Are there equivalent functions with different signature in OpenCL for nVidia and AMD APP SDK 3.0?

Tags: opencl, gpu

I have to multiply two matrices using AMD APP SDK 3.0. I found a good exemple on this link http://gpgpu-computing4.blogspot.ro/2009/09/matrix-multiplication-1.html

The problem is that it uses nVidia OpenCL and I can't find two methods and one constant. (The two Methods: shrCheckError(...) ; oclLoadProgSource(...) Constant: shrTrue)

I tried to include ALL the headers in the project but they are still undefined.
Are there equivalent methods in AMD APP SDK that I could use instead of those mentioned above?

Comment: I'm not familiar with those APIs so they must be something from the NVIDIA demo code. I'm guessing that shrCheckError checks and OpenCL return code; you can probably substitute and empty function. I'm guess oclLoadProgSource loads source from a file, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

First, let me give you a bit explanation. There are no such thing as NVidia OpenCL or AMD OpenCL. There is one OpenCL specification and vendors implement their drivers. These SDKs you mention are only sample codes provided by AMD and NVidia. Let's move onto the answer.

The example you are using actually implements matrix multiplication using the NVidia utility functions for OpenCL. You can add the necessary files to your project and they would work. If you go to this page of [NVidia OpenCL examples](https://developer.nvidia.com/opencl), you can download any source code from there. In the source code files, there is a folder called "common" and you can find the necessary files under that folder namely "oclUtils.h" and "oclUtils.cpp". The implementations of the functions you require are there.

There is also a folder named shared. Within that folder you should be able to find the functions and variables that start with shr, such as shrCheckError.